# How to fix this function that counts items based on their occurrence?

Tags: javascript

I have the following array:

```
const sales = [
  { name: 'a', count: 0 },
  { name: 'a', count: 0 },
  { name: 'b', count: 0 }
]
```

I want to count their occurrence:

```
const result = []
sales.forEach(sale => {
  if (result.includes(sale)) { // check if the item is in the new array
    sale.count += 1 // if it is, add one to count
  } else {
    result.push(sale) // if not, put the item in the array 
  }
})
```

But the if statement never returns true. Why is this and how to fix it?

Comment: "[How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)".

Comment: You never can have two same objects in that array of object literals, though they might have the same content.

Comment: `{ name: 'a', count: 0 } === {name: 'a', count: 0 }` will return `false`, because although those two objects contain the same properties and values they do not represent the same object in memory, which is what you are testing for (and how I imagine `.includes` works).  You probably want to compare the `name` property instead.

Comment: is `count` always 0 in sales object?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine equality for two JavaScript objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-to-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exists a good answer already at https://stackoverflow.com/a/201471/2358409 that explains why your solution doesn't work.

To make it work, you could transform individual `objects` in the `array` to `string`, and use a `Set` to count distinct elements.

```
const sales = [
  { name: 'a', count: 0 },
  { name: 'a', count: 0 },
  { name: 'b', count: 0 }
]

const count = new Set(sales.map(s => JSON.stringify(s))).size;
console.log(count)
```

Comment: It looks like OP wants to store the count of the similar objects in a property of the objects themselves, not just count the occurrences.

Comment: In his question he writes "I want to count their occurrence".

Comment: Yes, but in the code, there's `sale.count += 1`, which indicates where the output should actually occur.